# Kafka Streams - updating aggregations on KTable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a **KTable** with data that looks like this (key => value), where keys are customer IDs, and values are small JSON objects containing some customer data:

```
1 => { "name" : "John", "age_group":  "25-30"}
2 => { "name" : "Alice", "age_group": "18-24"}
3 => { "name" : "Susie", "age_group": "18-24" }
4 => { "name" : "Jerry", "age_group": "18-24" }
```

I'd like to do some aggregations on this **KTable**, and basically keep a count of the number of records for each `age_group`. The desired **KTable** data would look like this:

```
"18-24" => 3
"25-30" => 1
```

Lets say `Alice`, who is in the `18-24` group above, has a birthday that puts her in the new age group. The state store backing the first **KTable** should now look like this:

```
1 => { "name" : "John", "age_group":  "25-30"}
2 => { "name" : "Alice", "age_group": "25-30"} # Happy Cake Day
3 => { "name" : "Susie", "age_group": "18-24" }
4 => { "name" : "Jerry", "age_group": "18-24" }
```

And I'd like the resulting aggregated **KTable** results to reflect this. e.g.

```
"18-24" => 2
"25-30" => 2
```

I *may* be overgeneralizing the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935904/how-to-send-final-kafka-streams-aggregation-result-of-a-time-windowed-ktable):

> In Kafka Streams there is no such thing as a final aggregation... Depending on your use case, manual de-duplication would be a way to resolve the issue"

But I have only been able to calculate a running total so far, e.g. Alice's birthday would be interpreted as:

```
"18-24" => 3 # Old Alice record still gets counted here
"25-30" => 2 # New Alice record gets counted here as well
```

---

**Edit:** here is some additional behavior that I noticed that seems unexpected.

The topology I'm using looks like:

```
dataKTable = builder.table("compacted-topic-1", "users-json")
    .groupBy((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(getAgeRange(value), key))
    .count("age-range-counts")
```

---

#### 1) Empty State

Now, from the initial, empty state, everything looks like this:

```
compacted-topic-1
(empty)


dataKTable
(empty)


// groupBy()
Repartition topic: $APP_ID-age-range-counts-repartition
(empty)

// count()
age-range-counts state store
(empty)
```

---

### 2) Send a couple of messages

Now, lets send a message to the `compacted-topic-1`, which is streamed as a **KTable** above. Here is what happens:

```
compacted-topic-1
3 => { "name" : "Susie", "age_group": "18-24" }
4 => { "name" : "Jerry", "age_group": "18-24" }

dataKTable
3 => { "name" : "Susie", "age_group": "18-24" }
4 => { "name" : "Jerry", "age_group": "18-24" }


// groupBy()
// why does this generate 4 events???
Repartition topic: $APP_ID-age-range-counts-repartition
18-24 => 3
18-24 => 3
18-24 => 4
18-24 => 4

// count()
age-range-counts state store
18-24 => 0
```

---

So I'm wondering:

- Is what I'm trying to do even possible using Kafka Streams 0.10.1 or 0.10.2? I've tried using `groupBy` and `count` in the DSL, but maybe I need to use something like `reduce`?
- Also, I'm having a little trouble understanding the circumstances that lead to the `add` reducer and the `subtract` reducer being called, so any clarification around any of these points will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have your original `KTable` containing `id -> Json` data (let's call it `dataKTable`) you should be able to get what you want via

```java
KTable countKTablePerRange
    = dataKTable.groupBy(/* map your age-range to be the key*/)
                .count("someStoreName");
```

This should work for all versions of Kafka's Streams API.

**Update**

About the 4 values in the re-partitioning topic: that's correct. Each update to the "base `KTable`" writes a record for it's "old value" and it's "new value". This is required to update the downstream `KTable` correctly. The old value must be removed from one count and the new value must be added to another count. Because your (count) `KTable` is potentially distributed (ie, shared over multiple parallel running app instances), both records (old and new) might end up at different instances because both might have different key and thus they must be sent as two independent records. (The record format should be more complex that you show in your question though.)

This also explains, why you need a subtractor and an adder. The subtractor removes old record from the agg result, while the adder adds new record to the agg result.

Still not sure why you don't see the correct count in the result. How many instanced to you run? Maybe try to disable `KTable` cache by setting `cache.max.bytes.buffering=0` in `StreamsConfig`.

Comment: See my edit. This isn't working for me :(  Any help will be very much appreciated. This seems so simple - but I don't understand the behavior I describe in the edit above.

Comment: Finally got it working. Somehow my state store was in a weird state. Disabling the cache and also resetting the topics in my dev environment resolved the issue. Thanks Matthias, you are always a lot of help :)

Comment: @foxygen i am facing the same issue where my groupingKey changes in your case (age group changes )but it does not call subtractor, could you please tell what was done to fix it.