# Kafka aggregation: Issue when grouping key changes

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are using kafka KTable for aggregation and below is the kind of data we receive in input
Input data - Transaction Detail (transaction Id, status, category, amount,.. )

We group the above based on below
Grouping Key - (status, category)

App logic

```
Grouped Stream. Aggregate(() -> new Instance(), (key, newVal, aggVal) - > addAmount(newVal). (key, oldVal, aggVal) - > removeAmount(oldVal));
```

Let's say we get below stream of data as (transaction I'd, status, category, amount)

> 1 - 1, pending, cash, 10   // (pending, cash) - 10  aggregated value
>
> 2 - 2, pending, cash, 20 // (pending, cash) - 30
>
> 3 - 3, actual, card, 15  //(actual, card) - 15
>
> 4 - 1. Pending, card, 9 //(pending, cash) - 30, (pending, card) - 9  - - - This is where we are getting problem

In #4 though the update the on the same transactionId 1, but the grouping key changes (from cash to card), now since the grouping has changed it doesnt call removeAmoutn() method but only addAmount() method is called.

Any idea on how we can be solve this issue where if the grouping changes it should take care of earlier aggregated data as well.

I found similar use case here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42685866/2699756

But not sure what was done yo fix this.

Comment: I guess you need to read the original input topic as `KTable` (not as `KStream`) to get proper update semantics.

Comment: This is working as expected, may be there was some other silly mistake. Just to complete the thread, posting it