# How to dedup key in the ktable

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

What are the ways to dedup the key in the windowed k-table?

Added transform based on the solutions provided in the other threads,but still seeing the same count.Can somebody tell whats wrong in this?

```
final KTable<Windowed<String>, Long> aggregated = feeds
            .selectKey((k, v) -> v.getUserId().toString())
            .transform(() -> new Transformer<String, AvroMessage, KeyValue<String, AvroMessage>>() {
                private ProcessorContext context;

                @Override
                public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
                    this.context = context;
                }

                @Override
                public KeyValue<String, AvroMessage> transform(String key, AvroMessage value) {

                    Collection<String> list = Arrays.asList(key);

                    // Get collection without duplicate i.e. distinct only
                    List<String> distinctElements = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

                    key = distinctElements.toString();
                    // transform value using timestamp
                    return new KeyValue<>(key, value);
                }

                @Override
                public KeyValue<String, AvroMessage> punctuate(long timestamp) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void close() {
                }
            })
            // no need to specify explicit serdes because the resulting key and value types match our default serde settings
            .groupByKey()
            .count(TimeWindows.of(windowSizeMs),STATE_STORE);
```

output:

```
[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000002]: [227338224@1517605200000] , (2<-null)
```

Expected

```
[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000002]: [227338224@1517605200000] , (1<-null)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send final kafka-streams aggregation result of a time windowed KTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935904/how-to-send-final-kafka-streams-aggregation-result-of-a-time-windowed-ktable)

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921281/how-to-write-only-final-output-of-kstreams-windowed-operation