# 2 step windowed aggregation with Kafka Streams DSL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Suppose I have a stream "stream-1" consisting of 1 datapoint every second and I'd like to calculate a derived stream "stream-5" which contains the sum using a hopping window of 5 seconds and another stream "stream-10" which is based off "stream-5" containing the sum using a hopping window of 10 seconds. The aggregation needs to be done for each key separately and I'd like to be able to run each step in a different process. It is not a problem in itself if stream-5 and stream-10 contain updates for the same key/timestamp (so I don't necessarily need [How to send final kafka-streams aggregation result of a time windowed KTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935904/how-to-send-final-kafka-streams-aggregation-result-of-a-time-windowed-ktable?rq=1)) as long as the last values are correct.

Is there an (easy) way to solve this using the high-level Kafka Streams DSL? So far I fail to see an elegant way to deal with the intermediate updates produced on stream-5 due to the aggregation.

I know the intermediate updates can be somehow controlled with the `cache.max.bytes.buffering` and `commit.interval.ms` settings but I don't  think any setting can guarantee in all cases that no intermediate values will be produced. Also I could try converting "stream-5" to a KTable on read with the timestamp part of the key, but then it seems KTable does not support windowing operations like KStreams do.

This is what I have so far and which fails due to the intermediate aggregate values on stream-5

```
Reducer<DataPoint> sum = new Reducer<DataPoint>() {                                                                           
    @Override                                                                                                                 
    public DataPoint apply(DataPoint x, DataPoint y) {                                                                        
        return new DataPoint(x.timestamp, x.value + y.value);                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                         
 };                                                                                                                           

 KeyValueMapper<Windowed<String>, DataPoint, String> strip = new 
           KeyValueMapper<Windowed<String>, DataPoint, String>() {      
      @Override                                                                                                               
      public String apply(Windowed<String> wKey, DataPoint arg1) {                                                            
          return wKey.key();                                                                                                  
      }                                                                                                                       
 };                                                                                                                           

KStream<String, DataPoint> s1 = builder.stream("stream-1");                                                                      

s1.groupByKey()                                                                                                               
       .reduce(sum, TimeWindows.of(5000).advanceBy(5000))                                                                     
       .toStream()                                                                                                            
       .selectKey(strip)                                                                                                      
       .to("stream-5");                                                                                                          

KStream<String, DataPoint> s5 = builder.stream("stream-5");                                                                      

s5.groupByKey()                                                                                                               
       .reduce(sum, TimeWindows.of(10000).advanceBy(10000))                                                                   
       .toStream()                                                                                                            
       .selectKey(strip)                                                                                                      
       .to("stream-10");
```

Now if stream-1 contains intputs (the key is just KEY)

```
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":1.0}
KEY {"timestamp":1000,"value":1.0}
KEY {"timestamp":2000,"value":1.0}
KEY {"timestamp":3000,"value":1.0}
KEY {"timestamp":4000,"value":1.0}
KEY {"timestamp":5000,"value":1.0}
KEY {"timestamp":6000,"value":1.0}
KEY {"timestamp":7000,"value":1.0}
KEY {"timestamp":8000,"value":1.0}
KEY {"timestamp":9000,"value":1.0}
```

stream-5 contains the correct (final) values:

```
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":1.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":2.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":3.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":4.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":5.0}
KEY {"timestamp":5000,"value":1.0}
KEY {"timestamp":5000,"value":2.0}
KEY {"timestamp":5000,"value":3.0}
KEY {"timestamp":5000,"value":4.0}
KEY {"timestamp":5000,"value":5.0}
```

but stream-10 is wrong (final value should be 10.0) because it also takes into account the intermediate values on stream-5:

```
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":1.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":3.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":6.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":10.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":15.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":21.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":28.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":36.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":45.0}
KEY {"timestamp":0,"value":55.0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the results of all aggregations are KTables, which means the records produced to their output topic represent a changlog. However, when you subsequently load them as a stream, the downstream aggregations will be double-counting then.

Instead, you need to load the intermediate topic as tables, not streams. However, you will not be able to use windowed aggregations on them then, as those are only available on streams.

You can use the following pattern to accomplish a windowed aggregation over tables instead of streams:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Windowed+aggregations+over+successively+increasing+timed+windows

If you want to run each step in a separate process you can adapt that, just remember to load intermediate tables using builder.table(), not builder.stream().

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looking forward to an update on how to prevent infinite growth of the state store size with that approach.