# Unexpected key after count operation in Kafka streams.

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have the following logical flow in kafka streams:

```
stream.map((nullKey, rawData) -> KeyValue.pair(somekey(rawData), rawData))
            .filter((k, v) -> somefilterning(v))
            .groupByKey()
            .count(TimeWindows.of(3600).until(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(7200)), "someStateStore")
            .foreach((k, v) -> print(k.window().start()));
```

The parameters passed to the count method are the same as shown above and thus, it should aggregate the keys in a (logical) hourly window, i.e. all keys arrived between 11:00 and 12:00 should be aggregated together.

To validate that, I'm printing the window start time (or at least this is what I expect it to be) in the foreach call. My `COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG` is set to 2 min, so count outputs should be flushed every 2min and I expected the key.window.start() to be constant between flushes (assuming of course flushes of same logical hours).

Instead, I see many different start() values:

```
     timestamp    time
0   1508068706  11:58:26
1   1508068713  11:58:33
2   1508068720  11:58:40
3   1508068728  11:58:48
4   1508068735  11:58:55
5   1508068742  11:59:02
```

Which is very different than the logical hour (11:00). It is also not related to the 2min commit interval, as you can see timestamps with 8 sec difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple parts to this answer:

- first, Kafka Streams does update a window continuously and emits the current result after each update (also compare [How to send final kafka-streams aggregation result of a time windowed KTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935904/how-to-send-final-kafka-streams-aggregation-result-of-a-time-windowed-ktable) and https://www.confluent.io/blog/watermarks-tables-event-time-dataflow-model/)
- second, the internally used cache (cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#memory-management) to deduplicate consecutive updates to the same key, emits data every time it needs to make space for a new record (based on LRU strategy); thus, it can emit between commits -- it's also completely flushed on commit
- third, your specify window is of size `3600` and this value is in ms -- not seconds; I guess you wanted to do `TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3600))`

Comment: thanks. good catch about the ms vs sec, but also about the cach size. I guess changing the ms to sec will not help unless I will also increase the cache size.