# Multiple calls to operation after windowed aggregation for every message

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Following is the windowing operation I have written in Kafka Streams

```java
KTable<Windowed<String>, Test> testWinAlerts = testRecords
    .groupByKey()
    .aggregate(new TestInitilizer(), 
               new minMaxCalculator(),
               TimeWindows.of(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5))
                          .advanceBy(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)),
               MessageSerde,
               "win-counts")
    .filter((k,v)->{
            //Some Operation
                return (condition);
            })
    .toStream((k,v)->k.toString())
    .to(Serdes.String(),MessageSerde,"Window-topic");
```

But in this operation, filter operation gets called each time new messege comes and updates aggregation. For every new messege alert is written into `"Window-topic"` topic. Instead what I want is,
 filter operation should be executed once per window and final result should be written to `"Window-topic"` once per window(5,1). Is there any way we can do this and reduce these multiple calls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send final kafka-streams aggregation result of a time windowed KTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935904/how-to-send-final-kafka-streams-aggregation-result-of-a-time-windowed-ktable)

Comment: Please note that in Kafka Streams 1.0.0 includes wall clock time punctuation, so although windows have no "end", you can set up a periodic check on windows that recently "ended" and respond accordingly.