# Abnormalities occur when using the Kafka Streams Tumbling window

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

!!Test environment

- A producer who sends a message with the key 'A' once a second.
- Kafka Streams (Java Code) tumbling window every 10 seconds.
- 10 messages per 10 seconds should be received and duplicates occur at regular intervals as shown below.
- This must be resolved.

!!Current Results

(timestemp, key, Number of messages per tumbling window)

(1544079700000L, 'A', 10)

(1544079710000L, 'A', 10)

(1544079720000L, 'A', 10)

**(1544079730000L, 'A', 9)**

**(1544079730000L, 'A', 10)**

(1544079740000L, 'A', 10)

(1544079750000L, 'A', 10)

**(1544079760000L, 'A', 9)**

**(1544079760000L, 'A', 10)**

(1544079770000L, 'A', 10)

(1544079780000L, 'A', 10)

(1544079790000L, 'A', 9)

!! TumblingWindowKafkaStream.java (Use Kafka Streams)
`

```
ackage io.github.timothyrenner.kstreamex.tumblingwindow;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindows;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStreamBuilder;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;
/** Demonstrates tumbling windows.
 *
 * @author Timothy Renner
 */
public class TumblingWindowKafkaStream {
    /** Runs the streams program, writing to the "long-counts-all" topic.
     *
     * @param args Not used.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,
            "tumbling-window-kafka-streams");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            "localhost:9090,localhost:9091,localhost:9092");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_CONFIG,
            "localhost:2181");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
            Serdes.ByteArray().getClass().getName());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,
            Serdes.Long().getClass().getName());
        KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
        KStream<byte[], byte[]> longs = builder.stream(
            Serdes.ByteArray(), Serdes.ByteArray(), "t2");
        // The tumbling windows will clear every ten seconds.
        KTable<Windowed<byte[]>, Long> longCounts =
            longs.groupByKey()
                 .count(TimeWindows.of(10000L)
                                   .until(10000L),
                        "t2-counts");
        // Write to topics.
        longCounts.toStream((k,v) -> k.key())
                  .to(Serdes.ByteArray(),
                      Serdes.Long(),
                      "t2-counts-all");
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, config);
        streams.start();
        } // Close main.
} // Close TumblingWindowKafkaStream.
```

`

Comment: These are not duplicates, but updates. Check out this questions for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935904/how-to-send-final-kafka-streams-aggregation-result-of-a-time-windowed-ktable